# Проблема с API Python - запрос к Wordstat Яндекс через Python API

Tags: python, парсер, яндекс-директ

Изучаю [документацию к WordStat Яндекса](https://yandex.ru/dev/direct/doc/dg-v4/reference/CreateNewWordstatReport-docpage/). Составляю запрос с теми же фразами, что и в примере

```
import json
link = "https://api.direct.yandex.ru/v4/json/"
params = {"method": "CreateNewWordstatReport",
         "param": {'Phrases': [u'пух -винни',u'синтепон'],
                   'GeoID': [213]},
         "format": 'json'
        }
r = requests.get(link, params)
#r.encoding = 'utf-8-sig'
#obj = BeautifulSoup(r.text, 'html.parser')
r.json()
```

Выдаётся

```
{'error_str': 'Invalid request method',
 'error_code': 512,
 'error_detail': 'The HTTP request method must be POST'}
```

Answer (score 1):

Читайте текст ошибки: `The HTTP request method must be POST`. Исправляйте ее.

```
# Вместо requests.get(link, params)
r = requests.post(link, params) # post-запрос
```

Получите новую ошибку

```
# {'error_str': 'Invalid request', 'error_code': 501, 'error_detail': 'Invalid JSON request'}
```

В примерах документации было найдено следующее форматирование

```
r = requests.post(link, json.dumps(params, ensure_ascii=False).encode('utf8'))
```

И снова получите новую ошибку

```
# {'error_detail': '', 'error_code': 53, 'error_str': 'Authorization error'}
```

Полный код

```
import requests
import json

link = "https://api.direct.yandex.ru/v4/json/"
params = {
   "method": "CreateNewWordstatReport",
   "param": {
      'Phrases': ['пух -винни', 'синтепон'],
      'GeoID': [213]
   },
   "token": "token"
}
r = requests.post(link, json.dumps(params, ensure_ascii=False).encode('utf8'))
print(r.json())
```

И даже если вы зарегистрируете приложение и получите токен, опять будет ошибка

```
# {'error_detail': 'You need to fill out an app access request in the Direct interface and wait for confirmation', 'error_code': 58, 'error_str': 'No access'}
```

Для ее исправления уже нужно создавать заявку на доступ к API, [подробнее](https://yandex.ru/dev/direct/doc/dg-v4/concepts/register-docpage/).

Comment: Спасибо, отправила заявку, жду. Пока написала через Selenium, кажется, вся необходимая информация собралась